# Python Relative Imports and Packages

Tags: python, import, package

I'm trying to create a package and I have a tree structure that looks like this:

```
dionesus/
  setup.py
  dionesus/
    __init__.py
    dionesus.py
```

Dionesus.py has a class called Dionesus. The **init**.py is empty.

How do I import the class Dionesus without having to specify the top level folder?

I have to do:

```
import dionesus
d = dionesus.dionesus.Dionesus()
```

I would like import statements to look like:

```
import dionesus
d = dionesus.Dionesus()
```

Comment: In the future, if you're asking questions about packages, relative imports, or other things that have dramatic differences between Python versions, please list the version number(s) you care about. In this case, except for the errors/incorrect behavior you'll get if you screw up, everything should be the same from 2.5 on (IIRC), but you wouldn't know that in advance unless you already knew the answer.

Answer (score 3):

First, you can still use an absolute import, just using the `from … import` form:

```
from dionesus import dionesus
d = dionesus.Dionesus()
```

This will obviously be problematic if you ever need to import both dionesus and dionesus.dionesus in the same module, but that's pretty much implicit in the desire to give them both the same non-disambiguated name…

Alternatively, if you're in a parent or sibling or other relative of dionesus.dionesus, you can use a relative import. Depending on where you are, it'll be different (that's what relative means, after all); you may be importing from `.`, `.dionesus`, `..`, etc. But wherever it is, it's the same `from … import` form as above, just with a relative name instead of an absolute one. (In fact, relative imports *always* use the `from` form.)

```
from . import dionesus
d = dionesus.Dionesus()
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Corrected the typo. The file should be dionesus.py with a class inside it called Dionesus.

Comment: @J.W.: OK, removed the note at the end.